# The name 'joints' does not exist in the current context and "figure" is never used

Tags: c#, wpf-controls

I have a problem with this error "The name 'joints' does not exist in the current context " . I am trying to learn an example presented in a book for tracking skeleton with kinect . I have followed all the steps but I can't understand why i have this error. Maybe someone who understand all code can help me.

This is my code:

```
        private void KinectDevice_SkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
        {
           using(SkeletonFrame frame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
           {
               if (frame != null)
               {
                   Polyline figure;
                   Brush userBrush;
                   Skeleton skeleton;
                   LayoutRoot.Children.Clear();
                   frame.CopySkeletonDataTo(this._FrameSkeletons);

                   for(int i = 0; i < this._FrameSkeletons.Length; i++)
                   {
                       skeleton = this._FrameSkeletons[i];
                       if(skeleton.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked)
                       {
                           userBrush = this._SkeletonBrushes[i % this._SkeletonBrushes.Length];

                           //Draws the skeleton’s head and torso
                           joints = new [] { JointType.Head, JointType.ShoulderCenter,
                           JointType.ShoulderLeft, JointType.Spine,
                           JointType.ShoulderRight, JointType.ShoulderCenter,
                           JointType.HipCenter, JointType.HipLeft,
                           JointType.Spine, JointType.HipRight,
                           JointType.HipCenter };

                           LayoutRoot.Children.Add(CreateFigure(skeleton, userBrush, joints));

                           //Draws the skeleton’s left leg
                           joints = new [] { JointType.HipLeft, JointType.KneeLeft,
                           JointType.AnkleLeft, JointType.FootLeft };

                           LayoutRoot.Children.Add(CreateFigure(skeleton, userBrush, joints));

                           //Draws the skeleton’s right leg
                           joints = new [] { JointType.HipRight, JointType.KneeRight, JointType.AnkleRight, JointType.FootRight };
                           LayoutRoot.Children.Add(CreateFigure(skeleton, userBrush, joints));

                           //Draws the skeleton’s left arm
                           joints = new [] { JointType.ShoulderLeft, JointType.ElbowLeft, JointType.WristLeft, JointType.HandLeft };

                           LayoutRoot.Children.Add(CreateFigure(skeleton, userBrush, joints));

                           //Draws the skeleton’s right arm
                           joints = new [] { JointType.ShoulderRight, JointType.ElbowRight, JointType.WristRight, JointType.HandRight };
                           LayoutRoot.Children.Add(CreateFigure(skeleton, userBrush, joints));

                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
```

Comment: It is good SO etiquette to spell check your question and to format code correctly - please do so. I do not know that you can in this case but generally isolating the problem instead of posting a slough of code will help people help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work a little on your understanding of the C# basics.
In C# you always have to define a variable before it is used.
In this case you are changing the value of "joints" before telling the computer what "joints" is.

I believe that adding this by your other fields will solve your problem:

```
JointType[] joints;
```

As for "Figure is never used", this is not really an error...
It's just a warning telling you that you have code that doesn't do anything.